# What did June mean at the end of the Handmaids's Tale season 4 finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-handmaids-tale

At the end of the season 4 finale, June says:

> "I know. I'm sorry, just give me five minutes, okay? Just give me five minutes with her, then I'll go."

What does she mean? Where is she going? Does it mean she is going to turn herself in for what she did? Or does it mean that Luke doesn't want her to be around anymore? How did Luke understand what she has done?

Answer (score 6):

[According to this](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-features/handmaids-tale-season-4-finale-bruce-miller-interview-season-five-1234969092/):

> June’s choice to seek revenge on the villain of The Handmaid’s Tale, however, was not made easy. As her final words of the season indicate when she tells husband Luke (O-T Fagbenle), “I’m sorry. Just give me five minutes with her [Nichole] and then I’ll go,” she has potentially risked her freedom in order to further her war on the fascist regime of Gilead.

Bruce Miller, the creator and showrunner, explains:

> She says, “I need five minutes” — she’s five minutes from a reckoning. She doesn’t want to think about it or talk about what happened or what this means for five minutes. Certainly, everyone has been there. “Just let me be who I was for five more minutes and then I’ll decide who I’m going to be next.” What the hell is going to happen in five minutes? It can go a lot of ways and, the answer to your question is that I know what’s going to happen for the next five minutes, but I don’t know what happens after that. I don’t know because June doesn’t know. I know how she feels now, and that will lead me to the next thing.
>
> That moment at the end is her as a mother knowing she had chosen something that makes her feel like she can never be a mother again. She’s holding that baby and she’s thinking to herself this way, as a mother, and then she thinks of herself that way in the woods with dead Fred, and then she thinks of herself as a mother again and that’s where she is. Those two things are pushing up against each other. On one side, she is a mother and a caregiver, for Janine or her daughter or her friends or lovers; and then on the other side, she is a person who is getting vengeance for all of those people and for herself. You put those two things together when she believes, and I think we as the audience believe, that those two things can’t coexist.